# ncurses and C- Display output of 'df' command in ncurses window

Tags: c, terminal, ncurses, curses

I am relatively new to ncurses and was just wondering what would be the simple way to display the output of a command executed in terminal/the command line in the ncurses TUI that I am starting. i.e something like this psuedocode (which I know doesn't work, just to get the point accross :) The goal is to present a menu screen displaying various system information like available memory, network info, etc:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

initscr();
cbreak();
char command[] = "df";
printw(system(command));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by opening a *pipe* to the command (the example should use `"df"`, by the way).  Something like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *pp;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    if ((pp = popen("df", "r")) != 0) {
        char buffer[BUFSIZ];
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pp) != 0) {
            addstr(buffer);
        }
        pclose(pp);
    }
    getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I see. This is essentially what I was looking for thanks! Is there a way to control whats printed from the pipe ? I.e only print the first few characters?

Comment: I used `addstr` because it was quick (and did not require work to trim the newlines from the pipe).  You could use `addnstr` or `printw` to print just a few characters.